# How to avoid "IndexError: list index out of range" error in my Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the best way to fix the error given in the run? I also somewhat understand that a list cannot change while being iterated over, but it still seems a little abstract.

```
myList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", ]


for i in range(len(myList)):

    if i == 2:
        del (myList[4])

    print(i, myList[i])
```

--------------------------Run-------------------------------------------------

```
"C:\Python36\python.exe" 

Traceback (most recent call last):

0 A
  File "C:/Users/reading.py", line 10, in <module>

1 B

2 C

    print(i, myList[i])
3 D

4 F

IndexError: list index out of range

5 G

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Don't remove elements from lists while iterating over them.  Make a new list instead

Comment: Why you do not do: `del myList[4]` without a loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary, a list in Python can be changed (it is mutable), which is what you just did here:

```
del (myList[4])
```

In the beginning of the loop, `len(myList)` resolves to `6`. At the final loop, where `i = 6`,

```
print(i, myList[i])
```

is essentially

```
print(i, myList[6])
```

However since you shortened it to 5, Python raises the out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

**This is what [`list.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) is for!**

```
myList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
```

and remove the second element with:

```
myList.pop(2)
```

which will modify the `list` to:

```
['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
```

---

As pointed out in the comments, modifying a `list` that you are `iterating` over is never a good idea. If something more complicated but similar to this had to be done, you would make a copy of the `list` first with `myList[:]` and then iterate through changing the `copy`. But for this scenario, `list.pop` is the definitely the right option.

Answer (score 0):

How about with:

```
myList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
```

doing:

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
    if i == 2:
        del (myList[4])
    try:
        print(i, myList[i])
    except IndexError:
        None
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]

for i in range(len(myList)-4):
    if i == 2:
        del myList[4]
    print(i, myList[i])

0 A
1 B
2 C
>>> myList
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G']
```